# How to find geany any key in keyboard to continue?

Tags: geany

I want to find any key in geany.

I pressed some keys to continue. But I didn't find that key.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Learn what an [on-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is. Then take a look to [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.